# nginx load balance with IIS backend servers waiting Host header

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx

i have a ubuntu 10.04 with nginx /0.8.54 running as a load balance proxy
named: *www.local.com*

I have two IIS backend servers which responds on Host header request
*web1.local.com
web2.local.com*

**Problem:**
When i hit my nginx balancer on *www.local.com* my backend servers  respond with the default server blank webpage (IIS default page) since they are waiting for a right host header (e.g. *web1.local.com*)

my **nginx.conf**

upstream backend {
                server web1.local.com:80;
                server web2.local.com:80;
        }
        server {

```
      listen 80;
            location / {
              proxy_pass  http://backend;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $proxy_host;
            }
    }
```

any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the issue

The problem was first the missing `proxy_set_header Host $host;`
and i was missing the right virtualhost `ServerName www.domain.local` name
in the apache's conf file.

I was thinking that nginx is sending proxy headers internally using the server name listed in the upstream server list.

Answer (score 1):

Would not proxy_set_header Host $host; solve your problem?

Comment: no the [ proxy_set_header Host $host; ] does not solve the problem
and i dont know why...
if i hardcode [ proxy_set_header Host web1.local.com; ] it works for one backend...?!



inorder to work

Comment: the funny thing is that the proxy_Set_header host $host does not help any other hint i should check?